# When can "that" be replaced with an -ing form?

Tags: verbs, adverbs

Is there a general rule that allows to replace "noun + that + verb" with "noun + ing-form of verb"?

Consider this sentence:

Metal physical properties are key traits that determine the quality of products.

Can this be written as:

Metal physical properties are key traits determining the quality of products.

The second sentence already has a main verb and key traits is it an object? I am confused.

I would like to know in general when can "that" be omitted? If this question has already been asked I can't find it through the search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [1] *Metal physical properties are key traits* [*that determine the quality of*
> *products*].
>
> [2] *Metal physical properties are key traits* [*determining the quality of*
> *products*].

It's not a matter of omitting "that" in your second example. Though the bracketed clauses in [1] and [2] are semantically similar, they belong to different categories, the former a relative clause, the latter an *ing* participial clause.

In [2] "key traits determining the quality of products" is a noun phrase functioning not as object but as predicative complement of "be". The head word is "traits" and the participial clause is its modifier.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So what the general rule is that "that" can be omitted in a participial clause? I never heard about participial clause I will have to read up on it.

Comment: "That" does not introduce non-finite clauses such as participial ones, so the question of when "that" can be omitted in such clauses does not arise.

Comment: Yes. _That_ optionally introduces tensed complement clauses, like _I think (that) he did it_. Such clauses always have a tensed verb. Participial clauses, on the other hand, don't have tensed verbs -- participles aren't tensed.